# Видео на странице HTML5 проигрывается не во всех браузерах

Tags: html, html5, видео, iphone, safari

Добавил код на главную страницу сайта вместо фона:

```
 <video playsinline autoplay loop muted preload="auto">
        <source src="http://ip-адрес/static/img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://ip-адрес/static/img/video.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

Видео проигрывается во всех браузерах на компьютере, кроме safari, на iPhone не проигрывается ни в одном браузере. В чем причина может быть?

Comment: не срабатывает именно автоплей, или вообще не проигрывается?

Comment: Совсем не проигрывается. Если добавляю controls, то на айфоне появляются элементы управления видео, но само видео не проигрывается, при этом во всех браузерах, в том числе и в safari, на компьютере видео перестает проигрываться. Но мне controls не подходит, просто попробовал, потому что видео фоновое, как замена фону.